# Session Not Defined BooFuzz

Tags: python, security, fuzzing

I'm trying to run a fuzzing script against vulnserver. I've installed BooFuzz through pip. Somehow, it was working perfectly fine. However, after some changes to my base script it has popped up error pertaining to Session. I've reinstalled it and double checked yet the only error it reported was Session. Attaching my base script and error generated by the code.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Designed for use with boofuzz v0.0.1-dev3

import boofuzz

session = Session(
    target=Target(
        connection=SocketConnection("127.0.0.1", 9999, proto='tcp')))

s_initialize("fuzz")
s_string("KSTAT")
s_delim(" ")
s_string("AAA")
s_static("\r\n")

session.connect(s_get("fuzz"))
session.fuzz()
```

[image: Error Generated]

Answer (score 2):

I got the problem and it was due to my file name "boofuzz". Since Python was getting my filename as module it couldn't load modules of BooFuzz itself. Changed filename and removed pyc file generated by python. It ran seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Session:

```
from boofuzz import Session

session = Session(
target=Target(
    connection=SocketConnection("127.0.0.1", 9999, proto='tcp')))
```

Comment: I did both i.e importing everything inside boofuzz with ```from boofuzz import * ``` and ```from boofuzz import Session``` in both cases none worked for me.

Comment: Can you give me the error you get when using `from boofuzz import Session` ? I guess it's different from the error you showed on your post.

Comment: ```in <module> from boofuzz import Session ImportError: cannot import name Session``` This is what i got from what you suggested.